# How to retrieve the service account email and the keyfile in Google Cloud Composer?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have google cloud composer that run commands in a docker container using DockerOperator.

Now in the container, it will try to start a DataProc cluster. It's all good, but the problem is that the calls that are inside the container need the credentials. In fact I get errors about missing GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.

Is it possible to retrieve those in Airflow? I know this is not the best setup, but we are moving legacy software based on docker images to airflow and I am afraid there's no other way than this...

Comment: Are you using `DockerOperator` to launch containers within your Cloud Composer environment's GKE cluster, or to a remote Docker daemon somewhere outside of your environment? Are there any particular reasons why you've chosen to use `DockerOperator` instead of `KubernetesPodOperator`?

Comment: Yeah I am using the DockerOperator. The reason is that it seemed simpler given that what runs in the docker container is just a quick command, not a long running task...